# How to get html attr for Jquery DataTables selected row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have used [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) to display a list page of some contents. I am following [this](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html) example to perform a custom action on a selected row, similar to the delete example. However, in my case I have defined a data-id attribute where I have stored the Unique Id for that row.

```
<tr class="odd selected" data-id="349" role="row">
 <td class="sorting_1"> 1/04/2014 </td>
 <td> Grocery - Woolworths </td>
 <td> Grocery </td>
 <td> -58.33 </td>
</tr>
```

With the code below, I can access the selected row.

```
$("#btnSplitTransaction").click(function () {
        var recordId = table.row('.selected');
 });
```

However, when I try to access the data-id attr, with the below code, I do not get the correct result.

```
$("#btnSplitTransaction").click(function () {
        var recordId = table.row('.selected').attr('id');
 });
```

Anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did `attr('data-id')` not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by pyhsically selecting the table element and not relying on Datatables API to handle that. Below is the code I used:

```
var recordId = $('#tblTransaction tr.selected').eq(0).data('id');
```

Note: Here I am making an assumption that only 1 row can be selected. If you want to allow multiple rows to be selected, then you need to loop through each selection.

Answer (score 2):

Use `data()` instead of `attr()` to `get data-id`

```
$("#btnSplitTransaction").click(function () {
        var recordId = table.row('.selected').data('id');
});
```

If you want to use attr which is not recommended for data attribute give complete attribute name instead of id use  `data-id`

```
var recordId = table.row('.selected').attr('data-id');
```

Comment: when using data('id'), I get the following error: DataTables warning: table id=tblTransaction - Requested unknown parameter '2' for row 15. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4